# Django Transaction when open connection? @transaction.commit_manually @transaction.atomic

Tags: django, transactions, django-queryset

i want to know when is dbConnection opened

for exampel 
as follow logic 
Does wait db Connection to external_api_call

or not?

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def do_something():
    # 1. now db connection open?    

    # api_call
    response= requests.get(~~~~)

    # 2. or db connection opened here?
    aa= User.objects.get(id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Django** internally maintains DB connection. It uses persistent connection approach. But when the connection gets closed after a certain time and you hit a new database query, new connection is made by django and kept it in memory. And the same connection is re-used by multiple request until it expires.

You can read more about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/